# Codeigniter Print

Tags: codeigniter, printing

I have an array of data and I have a print button, when someone hits the print button the print dialog box appears, can anyone suggest a tutorial to do this?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the print dialog you need JavaScript:

```
window.print();
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.print();` from JavaScript will open the print dialogue for the current page.

To print only your array, you'll need to do several things:

1. Create a view which contains only the output of your array.
2. Add the `onload="window.print();"` to the body tag of that view.
3. Make the button link to this view, either via a popup or new page.